Inquiry on Salesforce App Security and Credentials Management
I am working on securing our company's Salesforce instance. To manage this, I am using API calls with a Salesforce app connection. However, I now need to identify:
Which apps have the consumer_key and consumer_secret?
What permissions these apps have?
When the consumer_secret was created and if it has been rotated?

If you are trying to retrieve the details for a Connected App, then you should start with the ConnectedApp object via the Metadata API.
